# Spark : No Encoder found for java.util.UUID

Tags: scala, apache-spark, dataset, encoder

I have a case class that contains a type field UUID.
I use anorm to parse a Postgres table and I want to transform the list to a Dataset.

When I create the Dataset, I have this error `No Encoder found for java.util.UUID`

```
def encoder[T: Encoder] = implicitly[Encoder[T]]

val parser = Macro.namedParser[Vehicle]

val result = SQL(s"SELECT * FROM $tableName").as(parser.*)

spark.createDataset(result)(encoder[Vehicle])
```

How can I manage this error ?

Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are no encoder for UUID in spark 2. you should use String instead.